# Iterate over a list in a template from a dictionary generated in View file

Tags: django, list, dictionary, iteration

I am creating a table in Django with columns of static and dynamic data. The dynamic data is easy to call from the database and loop through. The static data has been stored in the View as a dictionary. The problem I'm facing is when I need to iterate over a list in the template that comes via the dictionary. Here is the view code:

```
class NaturalAminoAcidInfoView(View):
template_name = "bacteria/naturalAAInfoList.html"

def get(self, request):

    # Creates a list of common bacteria in the minor, moderate, and widespread coloniser categories
    bacteria = Bacteria.objects.all()
    keylist = ['Minor', 'Moderate', 'Widespread']
    q_objects = reduce(or_, [Q(coloniser__contains=mykey) for mykey in keylist])

    common = bacteria.filter(q_objects).filter(gm_compilations__isnull=False)   
    common_count = common.count()

    amino_acid_dict = {
        "Alanine": {
            "text": "A non-essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via at least 6 transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/alanine.svg",
            "use": "alanine_use",
        },
        "Arginine": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium- and chloride-dependent symport ATB⁰,⁺ transporters, uniport CAT-1 transporters, and the high affinity antiport rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT (in exchange for a neutral AA) transporter.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/arginine.svg",
            "use": "arginine_use"
        },
        "L-Asparagine": {
            "text": "A non-essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via symport transporters (sodium-dependent SNAT2, sodium- and proton-dependent SNAT3, and sodium-dependent B⁰AT1).",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/l_asparagine.svg",
            "use": "l_asparagine_use"
        },
        "Aspartate": {
            "text": "A non-essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium(sym)-, proton(sym)- and potassium(anti)-dependent symport EAAT3 transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/aspartate.svg",
            "use": "aspartate_use"
        },
        "Cysteine": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium-dependent symport SNAT2 transporters, cystine-glutamate antiporter; alanine, serine, cysteine-preferring transporter 2 (ASCT2) and antiport 4F2hc/y⁺LAT2. It is also transported via antiports rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT and 4F2 hc/xCT (as cystine).",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/cysteine.svg",
            "use": "cysteine_use"
        },
        "Glutamate": {
            "text": "A non-essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium(sym)-, proton(sym)- and potassium(anti)-dependent symport EAAT3 and antiport 4F2 hc/xCT transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/glutamate.svg",
            "use": "glutamate_use"
        },
        "L-Glutamine": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via the sodium-dependent antiport ASCT2 transporter. Can also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/l_glutamine.svg",
            "use": "l_glutamine_use"
        },
        "Glycine": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via proton-dependent symport PAT1 & PAT2 transporters. Can also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/glycine.svg",
            "use": "glycine_use"
        },
        "Histidine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium-dependent symport SNAT2 transporters and the uniport CAT-1 transporters. Possibly transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/histidine.svg",
            "use": "histidine_use"
        },
        "Isoleucine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via antiport 4F2hc/LAT1 and uniport LAT4 transporters. Can probably also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/isoleucine.svg",
            "use": "isoleucine_use"
        },
        "Leucine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via antiport 4F2hc/LAT1 and uniport LAT4 transporters. Can probably also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/leucine.svg",
            "use": "leucine_use"
        },
        "Lysine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium- and chloride-dependent symport ATB⁰,⁺, antiport rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT (in exchange for a neutral AA) and uniport CAT-1 transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/lysine.svg",
            "use": "lysine_use"
        },
        "Methionine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium-dependent symport SNAT2, antiport rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT and uniport CAT-1 transporters. Can probably also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/methionine.svg",
            "use": "methionine_use"
        },
        "Phenylalanine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via antiport rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT and uniport CAT-1 transporters. Can probably also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/phenylalanine.svg",
            "use": "phenylalanine_use"
        },
        "Proline": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium-dependent symport SNAT2, proton-dependent PAT1 & PAT2 transporters. Can probably also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/proline.svg",
            "use": "proline_use"
        },
        "Serine": {
            "text": "A non-essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via the sodium-dependent transporters symport SNAT2 and antiport ASCT2, as well as the antiport rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT transporter.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/serine.svg",
            "use": "serine_use"
        },
        "Threonine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via antiport transporters ASCT2 and rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/threonine.svg",
            "use": "threonine_use"
        },
        "Tryptophan": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via the antiport 4F2hc/LAT1 transporter, the uniport TAT1 transporter, or the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/tryptophan.svg",
            "use": "tryptophan_use"
        },
        "Tyrosine": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via the antiport 4F2hc/LAT1 transporter.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/tyrosine.svg",
            "use": "tyrosine_use"
        },
        "Valine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via the antiport 4F2hc/LAT1 transporter and the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
            "image": "/media/image/naturalaa-info/valine.svg",
            "use": "valine_use"
        }
    }  

    amino_acids = [
        ('Alanine', amino_acid_dict['Alanine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Alanine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Alanine']['image']),
        ('Arginine', amino_acid_dict['Arginine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Arginine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Arginine']['image']),
        ('L-Asparagine', amino_acid_dict['L-Asparagine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['L-Asparagine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['L-Asparagine']['image']),
        ('Aspartate', amino_acid_dict['Aspartate']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Aspartate']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Aspartate']['image']),
        ('Cysteine', amino_acid_dict['Cysteine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Cysteine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Cysteine']['image']),
        ('Glutamate', amino_acid_dict['Glutamate']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Glutamate']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Glutamate']['image']),
        ('L-Glutamine', amino_acid_dict['L-Glutamine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['L-Glutamine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['L-Glutamine']['image']),
        ('Glycine', amino_acid_dict['Glycine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Glycine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Glycine']['image']),
        ('Histidine', amino_acid_dict['Histidine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Histidine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Histidine']['image']),
        ('Isoleucine', amino_acid_dict['Isoleucine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Isoleucine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Isoleucine']['image']),
        ('Leucine', amino_acid_dict['Leucine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Leucine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Leucine']['image']),
        ('Lysine', amino_acid_dict['Lysine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Lysine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Lysine']['image']),
        ('Methionine', amino_acid_dict['Methionine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Methionine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Methionine']['image']),
        ('Phenylalanine', amino_acid_dict['Phenylalanine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Phenylalanine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Phenylalanine']['image']),
        ('Proline', amino_acid_dict['Proline']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Proline']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Proline']['image']),
        ('Serine', amino_acid_dict['Serine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Serine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Serine']['image']),
        ('Threonine', amino_acid_dict['Threonine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Threonine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Threonine']['image']),
        ('Tryptophan', amino_acid_dict['Tryptophan']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Tryptophan']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Tryptophan']['image']),
        ('Tyrosine', amino_acid_dict['Tyrosine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Tyrosine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Tyrosine']['image']),
        ('Valine', amino_acid_dict['Valine']['use'], amino_acid_dict['Valine']['text'], amino_acid_dict['Valine']['image']),
    ]

    
    key2 = list(amino_acid_dict.keys())

    key = [amino_acid_dict[k]["use"] for k in key2]

    def process_data(field_name):
        consumer = common.filter(**{field_name + '__contains': '+'})
        bugs = []
        for bug in consumer:
            bugs.append(bug.species)
        return bugs
        
    for k in key:
        example_list = process_data(k)[:5]
        
    amino_acid_counts = {}
    for amino_acid, field_name, text, image in amino_acids:
        consumers = common.filter(**{field_name + '__contains': '+'})
        common_consumers = consumers.filter(gm_compilations__isnull=False).annotate(compilation_count=Count('gm_compilations', distinct=True))
        common_consumers_count = common_consumers.count()
        amino_acid_count = consumers.count()
        total_count = Bacteria.objects.filter(**{field_name + '__contains': '+'}).count()
        most_common_bugs = []
        most_common = [bug for bug in common_consumers if bug.gm_compilations and (bug.gm_compilations.count(',') + 1) >= 1]
        for bug in most_common:
            most_common_bugs.append(bug.species)
        most_common_bugs_examples = set(most_common_bugs[:5])

        amino_acid_counts[amino_acid] = {
            'common_consumers_count': common_consumers_count,
            'count': amino_acid_count,
            'total_count': total_count,
            'most_common': most_common,
            'most_common_bugs': most_common_bugs,
            'most_common_bugs_examples': most_common_bugs_examples,
            'text': text,
            'image': image,
        }

    context = {
        'bacteria': bacteria,
        'important_coloniser': common_count,
        'amino_acid_counts': amino_acid_counts,
        'amino_acids': amino_acids,
        'total_count': total_count,
        'common': common,
        'example_list': example_list,
    }

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Here is the template code:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Amino acid</th>
            <th>Common</th>
            <th>Example species</th>
            <th>All consumers</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for amino_acid, use, text, image in amino_acids %}

        <tr>
            <td>{{ amino_acid }}</td>
            <td> {% for bug in example_list %}
                <i><a href="url 'bacteria-detail' bug.slug" target="_blank">{{bug}};</a></i>
                {% endfor %}
            <td>
                {{ amino_acid_counts|dict_lookup:amino_acid|default_if_none:''|dict_lookup:'example_list' }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ amino_acid_counts|dict_lookup:amino_acid|default_if_none:''|dict_lookup:'total_count' }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ text }}
            </td>
            <td><img src="{{ image }}" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

This works fine, except for `{{ amino_acid_counts|dict_lookup:amino_acid|default_if_none:''|dict_lookup:'example_list' }}` which just displays the list like this: ['bacteria1', 'bacteria2' etc.]. Ideally, I'd like to iterate over this list and link urls to each list item, e.g.:

```
                {% for bug in example_list.items %}

                <i><a href="/bacteria/{{ bug.slug }}" target="_blank">{{bug}};</a></i>

                {% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to do this either in the template or in the view?

Comment: Can you add the code of the view please ?

Comment: I've added the view code and adjusted the template code to match your suggestion. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new modified code (below) solves all the issues I was having. It will be a useful generic template I can use for many other tables I need to create, where I'm only having to change a simple list of substrates and any specific text for each substrate. Here is the View code:

```
class NaturalAminoAcidInfoView(View):
template_name = "bacteria/naturalAAInfoList.html"

def get(self, request):

    # Creates a list of common bacteria in the minor, moderate, and widespread coloniser categories
    bacteria = Bacteria.objects.all()
    keylist = ['Minor', 'Moderate', 'Widespread']
    q_objects = reduce(or_, [Q(coloniser__contains=mykey) for mykey in keylist])

    common = bacteria.filter(q_objects).filter(gm_compilations__isnull=False)   
    common_count = common.count()

    def generate_bacterium_list(amino_acid):
        consumers = common.filter(**{amino_acid.lower() + '_use__contains': '+'})
        bacterium_list = []
        for bacteria in consumers:
            bacterium_list.append(bacteria)
        return bacterium_list
            
    amino_acid_dict = {}

    text_dict = {
        "Alanine": {
            "text": "A non-essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via at least 6 transporters.",
        },
        "Arginine": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium- and chloride-dependent symport ATB⁰,⁺ transporters, uniport CAT-1 transporters, and the high affinity antiport rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT (in exchange for a neutral AA) transporter.",
        },
        "L_Asparagine": {
            "text": "A non-essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via symport transporters (sodium-dependent SNAT2, sodium- and proton-dependent SNAT3, and sodium-dependent B⁰AT1).",
        },
        "Aspartate": {
            "text": "A non-essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium(sym)-, proton(sym)- and potassium(anti)-dependent symport EAAT3 transporters.",
        },
        "Cysteine": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium-dependent symport SNAT2 transporters, cystine-glutamate antiporter; alanine, serine, cysteine-preferring transporter 2 (ASCT2) and antiport 4F2hc/y⁺LAT2. It is also transported via antiports rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT and 4F2 hc/xCT (as cystine).",
        },
        "Glutamate": {
            "text": "A non-essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium(sym)-, proton(sym)- and potassium(anti)-dependent symport EAAT3 and antiport 4F2 hc/xCT transporters.",
        },
        "L_Glutamine": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via the sodium-dependent antiport ASCT2 transporter. Can also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
        },
        "Glycine": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via proton-dependent symport PAT1 & PAT2 transporters. Can also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
        },
        "Histidine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium-dependent symport SNAT2 transporters and the uniport CAT-1 transporters. Possibly transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
        },
        "Isoleucine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via antiport 4F2hc/LAT1 and uniport LAT4 transporters. Can probably also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
        },
        "Leucine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via antiport 4F2hc/LAT1 and uniport LAT4 transporters. Can probably also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
        },
        "Lysine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium- and chloride-dependent symport ATB⁰,⁺, antiport rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT (in exchange for a neutral AA) and uniport CAT-1 transporters.",
        },
        "Methionine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium-dependent symport SNAT2, antiport rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT and uniport CAT-1 transporters. Can probably also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
        },
        "Phenylalanine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via antiport rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT and uniport CAT-1 transporters. Can probably also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
        },
        "Proline": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via sodium-dependent symport SNAT2, proton-dependent PAT1 & PAT2 transporters. Can probably also be transported with the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
        },
        "Serine": {
            "text": "A non-essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via the sodium-dependent transporters symport SNAT2 and antiport ASCT2, as well as the antiport rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT transporter.",
        },
        "Threonine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via antiport transporters ASCT2 and rBAT/b⁰,⁺AT.",
        },
        "Tryptophan": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via the antiport 4F2hc/LAT1 transporter, the uniport TAT1 transporter, or the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
        },
        "Tyrosine": {
            "text": "A conditionally essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via the antiport 4F2hc/LAT1 transporter.",
        },
        "Valine": {
            "text": "An essential AA. After peptidase hydrolysis, it is absorbed through brush border cells of the small intestine, via the antiport 4F2hc/LAT1 transporter and the neutral AA B⁰AT1 and ATB⁰,⁺ transporters.",
        }
    }

    for amino_acid_name in ["Alanine", "Arginine", "L_Asparagine", 'Aspartate', 'Cysteine', 'Glutamate', 'L_Glutamine', 'Glycine', 'Histidine', 'Isoleucine', 'Leucine', 'Lysine', 'Methionine', 'Phenylalanine', 'Proline', 'Serine', 'Threonine', 'Tryptophan', 'Tyrosine', 'Valine']:
        amino_acid_dict[amino_acid_name] = {
            "text": text_dict.get(amino_acid_name, {}).get("text", ""),
            "image": amino_acid_name.lower() + ".svg",
            "use": amino_acid_name.lower() + "_use",
            "bacterium": generate_bacterium_list(amino_acid_name)[:7]
        }

    amino_acids = []

    for amino_acid in amino_acid_dict:
        name = amino_acid
        use = amino_acid_dict[amino_acid]['use']
        text = amino_acid_dict[amino_acid]['text']
        image = amino_acid_dict[amino_acid]['image']
        bacterium = amino_acid_dict[amino_acid]['bacterium']
        
        amino_acids.append((name, use, text, image, bacterium))

        
    amino_acid_counts = {}
    for amino_acid, field_name, bacterium, text, image in amino_acids:
        consumers = common.filter(**{field_name + '__contains': '+'})
        common_consumers = consumers.filter(gm_compilations__isnull=False).annotate(compilation_count=Count('gm_compilations', distinct=True))
        common_consumers_count = common_consumers.count()
        amino_acid_count = consumers.count()
        total_count = Bacteria.objects.filter(**{field_name + '__contains': '+'}).count()

        amino_acid_counts[amino_acid] = {
            'common_consumers_count': common_consumers_count,
            'count': amino_acid_count,
            'total_count': total_count,
            'text': text,
            'image': image,
            'bacterium': bacterium,
        }

    context = {
        'bacteria': bacteria,
        'important_coloniser': common_count,
        'amino_acid_counts': amino_acid_counts,
        'amino_acids': amino_acids,
        'common': common,
        
    }

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

And here is the template code:

```
<table class="table table-sortable table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Amino acid</th>
            <th>Common</th>
            <th>Example species</th>
            <th>All consumers</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for amino_acid, field_name, text, image, bacterium in amino_acids %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ amino_acid }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ amino_acid_counts|dict_lookup:amino_acid|default_if_none:''|dict_lookup:'count' }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% for bact in bacterium %}
                <i><a href="/bacteria/{{ bact|slugify|lower }}" target="_blank">{{ bact }};</a></i>
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ amino_acid_counts|dict_lookup:amino_acid|default_if_none:''|dict_lookup:'total_count' }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ text }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="/media/image/naturalaa-info/{{ image }}" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [named URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names) and the {% url %} template tag.

```
<i>
{% for bug in example_list.items %}
  <a href="{% url 'my_app:bacteria' bug.slug %}" target="_blank">{{ bug }};</a>&nbsp;
{% endfor %}
</i>
```

In your urls.py, you should have a named URL like this :

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "my_app"
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("bacteria/<slug:slug>/", views.bacteria_detail, name="bacteria"),
    ...
]
```

additional resources:

- [Path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)
- [URL examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: Close, but it gives the correct looking list of the last list in the query set. That is, it is iterating through this original list OK but overwrites each iteration leaving the last one repeated for each row in the column. I could solve this by splitting up each loop within the template table code, but I don't know how to do this.